# Equalize / Standardize response time of a web api call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to equalize my api responses to 2 seconds per call.  Do you think this is the proper way to do it (vb.net code)...

---

Dim timeToSleep = 2000 - Date.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds

''CODE TO EXECUTE HERE...

If timeToSleep > 0 Then Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeToSleep)

---

Does the Threading.Thread.Sleep function block only this api request?  What if someone else hits the api request while the Sleep function is executing?

Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can think of this being useful only in a testing scenario (load testing/user acceptance testing) to simulate a natural delay, and that this code would never ever touch production, this will work and your call will be delayed while other calls can run. **The question is which thread you are blocking:**

If you return a normal object or `HttpResponseMessage`, your call will block the ASP.NET's thread pool which in IIS 7 I think is 1000. Any more requests and your server returns 503 error.

If you return a `Task<T>`, then you are blocking .NET's ThreadPool threads - unless you specify a scheduler that uses another thread pool. Number threads in this pool will fluctuate between a [min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getminthreads) and [max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads) that can be set using static methods of `ThreadPool`.

I have a few posts on this subject on my [blog](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/aspnet-web-api-series-part-3-async-deep.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Threading.Thread.Sleep function block only this api request?
>   What if someone else hits the api request while the Sleep function is
>   executing?

Keep in mind that while you may try to adjust the relative output time of your api call by using sleep, it will not be reliably on *that* interval when latency, processing, other causes of slow/fast response time, etc, are factored in.

> Is there a better way I should be doing this?

if anything, I'd say fine tune your api call so it is as fast and lightweight as possible, and then do your intervals on the client side when calling it. (unless i'm misunderstanding why you are doing this.)

Also, you may want to look into a long polling solution.